# While checkin in tfs, Gated checkin Builds are not getting prompted. Directly getting checked in.

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines

I have gated check in TFS build,

While "checking in" in TFS its not bothering about gated check in and its directly getting checked in. What can be the reason for sudden change?

Answer (score 0):

Work around is shared below but its tough to follow with huge number of build definition. Even pragmatically its not affecting at all .

https://baskisumiwordpresscom.wordpress.com/2016/08/03/tfs-2015-update-2-gated-check-in-stops-building-before-checking-in-all-of-a-sudden/